# Efficient implementation of tensorial Rayleigh product

Tags: tensors

I am interested in the tensor product $\hat{B} = A \star B$ (which at least I know as Rayleigh product), defined with components

\begin{equation}
\hat{B}_{i_1 i_2 ... i_ n} 
= 
\sum_{j_1 = 1}^d \sum_{j_1 = 1}^d ... \sum_{j_n = 1}^d 
A_{i_1 j_1} A_{i_2 j_2} ... A_{i_n j_n} B_{j_1 j_2 ... j_n} \ .
\end{equation}

How would you implement this efficiently for tensors of arbitrary order? The following rude implementation using `TensorProduct` and `TensorContract` is just slow

```
rp1[A_, B_] := Block[
   {n, temp, ind},
   n = TensorRank[B];
   temp = ConstantArray[A, n];
   AppendTo[temp, B];
   ind = Table[{2*k, 2*n + k}, {k, n}];
   TensorContract[TensorProduct @@ temp, ind]
   ];
```

For example

```
n = 4; (*tensor order*)
d = 4; (*dimension*)
A = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {d, d}];
B = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, ConstantArray[d,n]];
AbsoluteTiming[res1 = rp1[A, B];][[1]]
```

> 0.146019

For fourth-order tensors you can do this as

```
rp2[A_, B_] := Block[
   {dim, i1, i2, i3, i4},
   dim = Length[A];
   Table[
    B.A[[i4]].A[[i3]].A[[i2]].A[[i1]]
    , {i1, dim}, {i2, dim}, {i3, dim}, {i4, dim}]
   ];
```

which is a lot faster

```
AbsoluteTiming[res2 = rp2[A, B];][[1]]
res1 == res2
```

> 0.0023153
>
> True

I am sure, I just dont have the right perspective on this, but how would you implement this for tensors of arbitrary order?

**EDIT:**
This is just based on yarchik's answer (please see his answer), just to give the code for general tensor order/rank

```
rp[A_, B_] := Block[
   {n, it, t1},
   n = TensorRank[B];
   it = RotateLeft@Range[n];
   t1 = B;
   Do[t1 = TensorTranspose[A.t1, it], {i, n}];
   t1
   ];
```

Testing

```
n = 4; (*tensor order*)
d = 10; (*dimension*)
A = RandomInteger[10, {d, d}];
B = RandomInteger[10, ConstantArray[d, n]];
AbsoluteTiming[res1 = rp[A, B];][[1]]
AbsoluteTiming[res2 = rp2[A, B];][[1]]
res1 == res2
```

> 0.00277906
>
> 0.770904
>
> True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can still speed up your code a lot

```
rp3[A_, B_] := Module[{a,c},
  a = Transpose[A];
  c = B;
  Do[c = Transpose[c.a, {2, 3, 4, 1}], {i, 4}];
  c
  ]
```

Now timing subroutine:

```
test[n_] := Module[{t0, t1, nrm, A, B,c0,c1},
  A = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
  B = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n, n, n}];
  t0 = Timing[c0 = rp2[A, B];] // First;
  t1 = Timing[c1 = rp3[A, B];] // First;
  nrm = Norm[Flatten[c1 - c0]];
  {n, t0, t1, nrm}
  ]
```

Now results:

```
p = Table[test[n], {n, 4, 14}]
(*{{4, 0.002887, 0.000146, 0}, {5, 0.007295, 0.000156, 0}, {6, 0.023915,
   0.000331, 0}, {7, 0.065420, 0.000586, 0}, {8, 0.180312, 0.001182, 
  0}, {9, 0.437847, 0.002028, 0}, {10, 0.942596, 0.003337, 0}, {11, 
  1.941590, 0.005264, 0}, {12, 3.863945, 0.008290, 0}, {13, 7.321387, 
  0.012194, 0}, {14, 12.766735, 0.019249, 0}}*)
```

Now plots

```
ListLogPlot[{p[[All, 1 ;; 2]], p[[All, 1 ;; 3 ;; 2]]}, Joined -> True]
speedup = Transpose[{p[[All, 1]], p[[All, 2]]/p[[All, 3]]}]
(*{{4, 20.}, {5, 47.}, {6, 72.}, {7, 112.}, {8, 153.}, {9, 216.}, {10, 
  282.5}, {11, 368.8}, {12, 466.1}, {13, 600.4}, {14, 663.2}}*)
ListLogPlot[speedup, Joined -> True]
```

***Comparison of run-times***

[image]

***Speed up***

[image]

> For sizes in the range of 4 to 14 we have a speedup in the range of 20
>   to 663 !

### Explanation

Matrix-matrix multiplication is much faster than a set of corresponding matrix-vector multiplications!

Comment: Thank you very much, I just did not see the transposition! That was the crucial point. Thanks!

Comment: @yarchik can you please explain `{2, 3, 4, 1}` in the `Transpose`? In particular, how to generalise this part of the function to arbitrary `n` and `d` (in the notation of the OP). Thanks!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The idea is to use matrix multiplication, which is a very efficient operation, for the computation of each sum. To this end, we need to change the order of indices of matrix `B`in such a way as to have the active one as the last one. Now concerning the generalization: `d` is the dimension of the inner sum in each matrix multiplication. Therefore, it is already taken care of. `n` is the number of sums= number of dimensions of `B`. To make it more general, we can write `Do[c = Transpose[c.a, RotateLeft[Range[n]]], {i, n}];`

Comment: Also possible: `Nest[A.Transpose[#, RotateLeft[Range[4]]] &, B, 4]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, it's a very nice concise way of writing, and functional too.