# How to apply a linear transformation to a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I would like to apply a linear transformation to a tensor. My linear transformation is encoded by a matrix, for example

`M = Table[m[i, j], {i, 4}, {j, 4}]`

Take some vectors

`V = Table[v[i], {i, 4}]`

`W = Table[w[i], {i, 4}]`

I apply the linear transformation to vectors with the dot operator

`M . V`

`M . W`

Now I would like to apply the same linear transformation to tensors, in a compatible ways. For a tensor of order two, the linear transformation is encoded by the tensor product matrix

`TensorProduct[M,M]`

But how do I apply it to a tensor? The dot operator doesn't give the right result. For example, imagine I want to apply my linear transformation to the following tensor

`TensorProduct[V,W]`

I would like to have that

`TensorProduct[M,M] . TensorProduct[V,W] === TensorProduct[M . V, M . W]`

But this is False. The dot operator is not the correct way. What is the right way? I would like to apply this linear transformation also to other tensors, not just tensors of the form `TensorProduct[V,W]`

Moreover, I would like to apply the linear transformation also to tensors of higher order, not just tensors of order 2.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to rotate a tensor of arbitrary rank using a transformation matrix. This can be done using the tensor product:

\begin{equation}
\hat{B}_{i_1 i_2 ... i_ n} 
= 
\sum_{j_1 = 1}^d \sum_{j_1 = 1}^d ... \sum_{j_n = 1}^d 
A_{i_1 j_1} A_{i_2 j_2} ... A_{i_n j_n} B_{j_1 j_2 ... j_n} \ .
\end{equation}

There's several implementations of this in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120043/efficient-implementation-of-tensorial-rayleigh-product). Here's one example:

```
rayleighProduct[transformationMatrix_, tensor_] := Block[{n, it, t1},
  n = TensorRank[tensor];
  it = RotateLeft[Range[n]];
  t1 = tensor;
  Do[t1 = TensorTranspose[transformationMatrix . t1, it], {i, n}];
  t1]
```

Some examples:

```
M = Table[m[i, j], {i, 4}, {j, 4}];
V = Table[v[i], {i, 4}];
Q = Table[q[i, j], {i, 4}, {j, 4}];

M.V == rayleighProduct[M, V]
M.Q.Transpose[M] == rayleighProduct[M, Q]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know the name Rayleigh Product. I tested it. The following command     `Simplify[rayleighProduct[M, TensorProduct[V, W]] -    TensorProduct[M . V, M . W]]`    Gives zero. It also works for tensors of order 3:  ` Simplify[rayleighProduct[M, TensorProduct[V, W, X]] - TensorProduct[M . V, M . W, M . X]] ` this also gives zero. So I think this is what I need!

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have 2 vectors V and W and construct the tensor product "t1=TesorProduct[V,W]". If you apply a linear transformation: M to the vectors V,W:  M.V,M.W. How do you then get "t2=TensorProduct[M.V,M.W]" from t1?

Well the simple answer is:

```
t2=M.TensorProduct[V, W].Transpose[M]
```

You can check this by a simple example:

```
n = 4;
M = Table[m[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}];
V = Table[v[i], {i, n}];
W = Table[w[i], {i, n}];

M. TensorProduct[V, W].Transpose[M] == 
  TensorProduct[M . V, M . W] // Simplify

( True *)
```

**Update**

The same can be written using "TensorContract" in a form that can easily be generalized to more dimensions:

```
TensorProduct[M . V, M . W] == 
  TensorContract[
   TensorProduct[M, V, M, W], {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}] // Expand

(* True *)
```

For more dimensions we may have e.g:

```
X = Table[w[i], {i, n}];
TensorProduct[M . V, M . W, M . X] == 
  TensorContract[
   TensorProduct[M, V, M, W, M, 
    X], {{2, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 9}}] // Expand 

(* True*)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know the transpose on the other side can work for tensors of order 2. But How can I generalize this for tensors of order 3 or higher? George's answer works for tensors of any order.

Comment: With the right notation, this can easily be generalized for higher tensors. Look my update.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `TensorProduct` and `TensorContract` like this becomes quickly super slow...

Comment: I see, I had never used TensorContract before. But there is still an issue with this solution. You have to imagine that I don't know V and W, I only have one tensor (in this case, TensorProduct[V,W]).  So, what I need to do is to permute the factors with reference to your solution. The right order is `TensorContract[TensorProduct[M, M, V, W], {{2, 5}, {4, 6}}] `

Comment: With this order, I can now write the equivalent ` TensorContract[
 TensorProduct[M, M, TensorProduct[V, W]], {{2, 5}, {4, 6}}]` This contains only things I know.

Comment: As Henrik pointed out, this solution is super slow. It is already very slow with tensors of order 3.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was thinking about when I wrote the question. Very clean. I didn't know about TensorContract. In my code, I am now using the solution written by George, because it is much faster.